# sql function to change multiple dateformat into one dateformat

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, performance, sql-function

how to change multiple dateformat into one dateformat in sql?

currently, i'm using my java code. however, I would like to change using sql function so that I don't need to consume another connection between my java program and database.

My current code is below:

--

any pointer would be appreciated

Comment: if it's empty or null, i set empty value

Comment: for example, if value inside birthDate[0] is '2016/01', it will give 7. if birthdate is '2016', it will give 4. it can be 0 too cuz birthDate can be 'empty'

Comment: I tested this 

`DECLARE @finalDate nvarchar(20)
SET @finalDate = CONVERT(varchar, '2011/01' ,111);
print @finalDate;`

I got 2011/01 but i want finalDate to be '2011/01/01' 'YYYY/MM/DD' format

Comment: hey sorry, i got wrong answer your question :

birthDate[0].length is checking for 'YYYY' or 'MM', if the len is 4, i assume it's year. if the len is 2, I assume 'month'

Answer (score 2):

Did hardcode as below but i think it's poor code :(

`DECLARE @finalDate nvarchar(20)
SET @finalDate = CONVERT(nvarchar(15), '2011/01'+'/01' ,100);
print @finalDate;`